# django: exclude fields from validation dynamically

Tags: django, forms, validation, dynamic

I have one form to take care of both the add and modification of products.
When adding a product, I would like to exclude the *modifyAttribute* field from the validation, and when I modify a product, I would like to exclude the *addAttribute* field from the validation.

I am in "adding mode" when I enter a value for the *addAttribute* field and in "modification mode" when I enter a value for the *modifyAttribute* field (textboxes).

How to do that? Where? In the view? Form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might not be the perfect solution but I have finally designed 3 forms: 1 for the common fields, one for the add fields, and one for the modification fields. In my view, I always call 2 forms at a time and only those 2 need to be validated.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you override the form's `clean()` method, since you need to access multiple fields at once. It's easier to *add* validation to a field, since you can access cleaned values from the object's `self.cleaned_data` dictionary, so I would suggest you make *both* fields pass if present and then raise exceptions/modify data as you see fit depending on the case. The relevant documentation is [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/forms/validation/)

Example:

```
class YourForm(forms.Form):
    # Everything as before.
    ...

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(YourForm, self).clean()
        add_attribute = cleaned_data.get("add_attribute")
        modify_attribute = cleaned_data.get("modify_attribute")

        if modify_attribute and add_attribute:
            raise forms.ValidationError("You can't add and
                                     modify a product at the same   time.")

        if not modify_attribue and not add_attribute:
            raise forms.ValidationError("You must either add or modify a product.")
         # Always return the full collection of cleaned data.
        return cleaned_data
```

And then in your view you could do one thing if modify_attribute and another if add_attribute, since now you know only one of them is present.

Comment: Does your solution exclude any field from the validation?

Comment: It depends on how those fields are defined and what you mean by "excludes validation". If both fields are defined with `null=True, blank=True`, then my solution will validate that only one of the two is present. If neither field has `null=True, blank=True` then my solution won't work. This is what I was getting at when I said that it's easier to _add_ validation to a field than to remove it, so I suggest you make both fields optional.

Comment: Ok thanks, I prefer to look for another solution, I don't want my fields to be optional.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove field in form `__init__` method, for `ModelForm` it looks like:

```
class AddModifyForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AddModifyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.instance.pk:
            del self.fields['modifyAttribute']
        else:
            del self.fields['addAttribute']

    class Meta:
        model = YourModel
        fields = ['addAttribute', 'modifyAttribute', ...]
```

Comment: What does <self.instance.pk> mean? In my view, I use <if "modifBtn" in request.POST> to know when the form is in "modification mode". Can I use it in the init function? Can I pass a parameter such as modif=yes or no?